# Get the terms of a custom taxonomy for a specific author in author template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, author, terms, author-template

I am using a custom post type in my website and a custom taxonomy for it.

An author selects one or many terms before publishsing its post.

My goal is to display  authors pages in front end, so I am using `author.php` template file. This file is by default displaying the archive of posts written by the specific author. How can I add to this file the list of the custom taxonomy terms for the author published posts?

I give the following example if I wasn't clear in my explanation:

```
if Author-x has published:

**post1** with term1 , term2, term3
**post2** with term2, term5
**post3** with term1


then, in Author-x page I will have : term1, term2, term3, term5.
```

It is exactly the same principle as in user page in stack exchange. As you can see, there is a list of tags for each user which are tags of posts the user contributed in.

Thank you for your usual help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get  a list of the author posts then loop over the each post and get the terms used ex:

```
function list_author_used_terms($author_id){

    // get the author's posts
    $posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'custom_post_type_name', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'author' => $author_id) );
    $author_terms = array();
    //loop over the posts and collect the terms
    foreach ($posts as $p) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $p->ID, 'taxonomy_name');
        foreach ($terms as $t) {
            $author_terms[] = $t->name;
        }
    }
    return array_unique($author_terms);
}

//usage
echo implode(", ",list_author_used_terms(1));
```

Comment: Thank you @bainternet for your help. i will test and come back give feedback

Comment: test away , but remember its an example :)

Comment: I did all the necessary changes (changed post to custom post type name, and changed post_tag to my taxonomy name) but it is still giving me an empty array for author with id=1 even this author has posts with terms. also I print_r the $posts variable after get_posts and it is ok.!!!!

Comment: It is okey and thank you very much, I understand now that you gave me just the algorithm not the code. but you should know that the only mistake you did is : name instead of term_name. Perfect Bainternet.

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Comment: Thank you, but please to accept my edit so that your answer fit totally with it

Comment: Please Bainternet, I have an issue with the resulting array. I want to perform a foreach loop on it. Inside the loop I need to use get_term_link which requires a string in its first parameter. I know it is a php pure problem but I dont find solution to it. thanks again http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102894/get-used-terms-by-an-author-as-array-of-strings

Comment: `get_term_link` function requires that the first parameter should be the term_id or term_slug, not the term name, But I want to notice to you that this function has a weird behaviour in WP 3.5+. First it is not working even with term_id (only term_slug works). In addition, if you dont wrap it by `if (!is_wp_error(get_term_link($inter->slug,'wossom')))`, it blocks the rest of the page from executing. FYI.