# Get used terms by an author as array of strings

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, terms

I am using `list_author_used_terms` function below to get the terms used by a specific author (terms of a custom taxonomy 'wossom' for a custom post type 'aya-bi-aya').

```
function list_author_used_terms($author_id){

    $posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'aya-bi-aya', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'author' => $author_id) );

    $author_terms = array();

    foreach ($posts as $p) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $p->ID, 'wossom');

        foreach ($terms as $t) {
            $author_terms[] = (string)$t->name;
        }

    }
    return array_unique($author_terms);
}
```

In `author.php` template file, I want to display the terms used by the given author. I do like this:

```
<?php
$user = get_user_by('login',get_query_var('author_name'));

$used_terms=list_author_used_terms($user->ID);

foreach ($used_terms as $ut) {
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $ut,"wossom"); ?>"><?php echo  $ut; ?></a>
<?php
} 
?>
```

When I `print_r` the `$used_terms`, I get the correct array, but the `foreach` loop is displaying nothing.

I get the following error when I try to print seperately `get_term_link( $ut[0],"wossom");` :

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\wp-content\themes\twentyten\author.php on line
```

I know it is a pure php problem but I am really tired trying to resolve it. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `$ut[0]` as array, when your individual items in `$used_terms` seem to be strings, if I follow code right?

Comment: get_term_link first parameter should be string, which is not the case because $used_terms is not an array of strings. using  $ut[0] is only for testing. I hope I am not wrong.

Comment: Why isn't it array of string if your `list..` function seem to return precisely that ( `$author_terms[] = (string)$t->name;` )?

Comment: This is the illogical thing that is making me blocked. I didnt have at the beginning the (string), and even after adding it, my problem is not resolved.

Comment: Dump (with `var_dump()` for example) `$ut` right before place with error.

Comment: First thank you for your time. I tried var_dump(), it is making some change (displaying the string with some additional characters), but the error message remains.

Comment: Please add that to the question. By now your code is quoted differently in place error happens and you say that data is not in a form that code suggests it is.

Comment: @Rarst.Last time I was not understanding what does var_dump do. After using it I now see that my array fields are  always strings. and now I can detect at each step what is the format of my variables. I think (I am not sure yet) that what is returning WP_error is `get_term_link` since this function requires the first parameter to be term_id, term_slug, but not the term_name. I thank you very much for your time, I will be back here to post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned from Rarst and S_ha_dum two new nice techniques that I want to share with everybody beginner in coding PHP/Wordpress:

- `Var_dump` function is useful to check what is the nature of a
  variable during the steps of code.
- geting into the habit of verifying that you have the kind of data you
  think you have before you try to use that data. For example, performing `if (!is_wp_error($variable)) {}` when you read from Codex
  that $variable contains the return of a function that can be WP_Error.

More details can be found in comments and S_ha_dum answer.

**Solution to my problem:**

What was returning WP_error is `get_term_link` function which requires the first parameter to be term_id or term_slug, and not term_name. But I want to notice that only the term_slug worked for me not the term_id even Codex say this.

The code became:

```
foreach ($used_terms as $ut) {
  $inter= get_term_by( 'name',$ut,'wossom' );
  $link = get_term_link($inter->slug,'wossom');

  if (!is_wp_error($link)) {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo  $inter->term_id; ?></a>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which line that error refers to but this code works correctly if everything falls into place exactly right.

But there are actually several ways this could go wrong. For example, if `get_query_var('author_name')` is not set you get an error on this line:

```
$used_terms=list_author_used_terms($user->ID);
```

If a problem occurs here:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $p->ID, 'wossom');
```

then  you get and error here:

```
$author_terms[] = (string)$t->name;
```

Because `$t` will be a `WP_Error` object and not the `stdClass`object with term data that you expect.

Something very similar happens with this line:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $ut,"wossom"); ?>"><?php echo  $ut; ?></a>
```

I think the solution is to get into a habit of verifying that you have the kind of data you think you have before you try to use that data.

For example:

```
foreach ($used_terms as $ut) {
  $link = get_term_link( $ut,"category");
  if (!is_wp_error($link)) {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo  $ut; ?></a>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Comment: I thank you for giving me the the useful advice fo using `'!is_wp_error'`. When I used it for `$link`, the remaining part of `author.php` executed, which means that get_term_link `( $ut,"category");` is returning WP_error even if $used_terms is looking as stdClass when displayed. When I do `!is_wp_error` for `$t` variable, nothing change (`$used_terms` stay the same) Thank you S_HA_DUM for your time

Comment: Like I said, this works if everything lines up, but there are numerous places it could go wrong. You need to debug step by step to find all the points of failure.

Comment: I am here to emphasize on what you said. In addition, last time I was not understanding what does var_dump do (suggested as debug method by Rarst). After using it I now see that my array fields are always strings. and now I can detect at each step what is the format of my variables. I think (I am not sure yet) that what is returning WP_error is `get_term_link` since this function requires the first parameter to be term_id, term_slug, but not the term_name. I thank you very much for your time, I will be back here to post the solution. Thank you for your time.